# Is one of the inputs in this discrete H-bridge driver schematic inverted?

Tags: digital-logic, schematics

I'm writing some firmware for somebody else's board and would like to check in advance so I don't fry anything - could someone please confirm if the following h-bridge driver would operate with either H_BRIDGE_HI or H_BRIDGE_LO being driven logic high causing there respective MOSFET to conduct (one at a time obviously) or is one of the inputs meant to be driven with inverted logic? [image: H-bridge driver schematic]

Comment: Both are inverting. Startup should be interesting! :-)

Comment: So assuming the controller has pins low until start up is run this thing is conducting across the rails at start up? Thanks for the warning! Ill be sure to set them in the first lines of code [it's reverse engineered from a board already in production so it doesn't seem to be catastrophic].

Comment: Correct. That won’t help if the +VSW comes up before your MCU has booted. Cross conduction then it’s all over.

Comment: Checking the MCU datasheet all pins are floating inputs on start up - I assume R3 is specifically a pull down. Would the 3V3 after R9 be enough to ensure the low side input was driven high during power up? (meaning motor phase would be connected to the high side in the beginning)

Comment: That helps. Given correct pull-up or down, it's down to a race condition between +VSW and +3V3.

Comment: @norlesh Keep in mind the pin states of the mcu under reset or with an empty chip.

Comment: @Jeroen3 And fault cases and shutdown :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Q2 is on, V0 is off.
For Q2 to be on, Q1 must be on. (pnp, negative base current)
For Q1 to be on, `H_BRIDGE_HI` must be high. (npn, positive base current)

When Q5 is on, V1 is off.
For Q5 to be on, `H_BRIDGE_LO` must be high. (npn, negative base current)

They're both inverting.

Missing from this circuit is shoot trough prevention and dead time insertion.

And I think you can't turn on V0 on at all since all bootstrap voltage in C1 is being shorted as long as Q0 and Q2 conduct. Which they both do when Q1 is on.
I think Q2 should be an NPN, to conduct when Q1 is off. But maybe I'm wrong with this.

*Next time use a half bridge gate driver chip.*

Comment: Yeah the high side driver makes no sense as currently drawn. Def alert that "somebody else" before they get the boards back from mfg...

Comment: This is reverse engineered schematic from an already mass produced hoverboard control board so that ship has long since sailed - dead time is built in to the MCU PWM module (STM32F103)

Comment: @norlesh It's reverse engineered wrong, and will blow up when turned on.

Comment: well the physical circuit board hasn't blown up when tested on my desk using the old firmware so I guess something must have got mixed when recreating the schematic - the important part for me is just that I know which directions to drive the pins for the bridge to conduct.

Comment: @norlesh Well... In the high side there is still a problem, so it may not be inverting if Q2 isn't right.

Comment: Yea the high tide has both inverting and non-inverting paths in parallel; I gave up trying to work out which would win. Have you simulated this schematic?

Comment: Up until now I had taken it on face value the person that recreated the schematic got it rite - looks like I will be re-recreating the schematic today...

Comment: I will amend the original question once I confirm what Q2 is.

Comment: After checking under the microscope Q0 and Q2 are the same package which are marked with '1HD' on the board I have. this marking corresponds to a MMBT8550 PNP transistor according to it's datasheet.